# "Creating pipe: too many open files" error when running org-publish on large project

Tags: org-export, org-publish

I have an org project that has many `.org` files (more than 300). When I invoke `org-publish` in Emacs, after a while it aborts and shows:

```
...
...
Publishing file e:/git/blog.site.src/src/org/life/day-time-plan.org using `org-html-publish-to-html'
Parsing config file...
apply: Creating pipe: too many open files
```

- Emacs version: 24.5.1
- Org Mode version: 8.2.10
- OS: Windows 8

I found a similar issue here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs/issues/132

... but there doesn't seem to be a known fix. Can anybody help me with this? Any info is appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows or Unix?

Comment: @stsquad  Windows x64

Comment: You could be hitting the 512 open file limit. You could try manually executing _(org-publish-all t t)_ and see if that helps. The async call means a new process is created to do the actual publishing work.

Comment: @stsquad : i get this from \*Messages\*  when i execute `(org-publish-all t t)`:  `Initializing asynchronous export process 
Process 'org-export-process' exited abnormally` . didn't `org-publish` close the file when it process a `org` file done ?

Comment: @itsjeyd : thank you for improving grammar. sorry for my english .

Comment: it could just be the async method doesn't work well on Windows (async calls spawn a new instance of emacs and an _inferior_ process). Without having a Windows machine to try on myself I'm not sure what further advice I could offer.

Comment: On the off-chance that org-publish uses Windows Unix Services, then you can navigate to registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Services for Unix
and create a new DWORD entry called MaxOpenFlies and set its value to something higher than 2048 (default). Note that I vaguely recall that this limit is a per process limit.

Comment: @EmacsUser http://superuser.com/questions/495360/does-windows-8-still-implement-posix i think Services for Unix doesn't exist on win 8.1. thank you all the same.

Comment: @Jun, the only other registry key I know is tweaking MaxUserPort. If that does not work, perhaps its time to log a bug report with emacs.

Comment: @stsquad finally i use `(org-publish-project "xxxx" nil t)` to fix this problem, thx for your info : )